# How to use local images in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, image

As stated in [this Tutorial](http://ryanclark.me/going-native-with-react/), it would be easy to add a local stored image to an TabItem (or whatever component):

1. Add the image in Xcode to the `images.xcassets`.
2. Require it like so `icon={require('image!pencil')}` (Name of the image is "pencil")

What I get then is an exception in iOS-Simulator with the following text:

> Requiring unknown module "image!pencil". If you are sure the module is
> there, try restarting the packager

What is wrong here? The Tutorial? Or has React Native changed completely?

The code:

```js
class devdactic_tabs extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedTab: 'welcome'
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'welcome'}
                icon={require('image!pencil')}
                onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'welcome',
          });
      }}>
                <Welcome/>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'more'}
                systemIcon="contacts"
                onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'more',
            });
      }}>
                <More/>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
    );
}
```

[image: The images-xcassets]

Comment: i had the same issue. i solved it by naming the folder name to the exact name of the icons. In your case: pencil.imageset -> the images pencil.png and pencil@2x.png. After that restart the packager and build the app new. should work then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filenames has to be exactly the same as the resource name in images.xcassets.

For example, when you add a new image set named "foobar", all images assigned to this set has to be named as "foobar.png".
If you're using e.g. Glyphishpro-Images, the image files are prefixed with a number. If you then rename these images to the name without that number, you will get exactly this error!

I ran into this issue last days... Is it yours too?

Comment: i had the same issue. i solved it by naming the folder name to the exact name of the icons. In your case: pencil.imageset -> the images pencil.png and pencil@2x.png. After that restart the packager and build the app new. should work then

Answer (score 0):

Please follow an [official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-ios-app-using-images-xcassets) on how to add resources into iOS and Android projects.

Also make sure:

> NOTE: App build required for new resources
>   Any time you add a new resource to Images.xcassets you will need to re-build your app through Xcode before you can use it - a reload from within the simulator is not enough.

Comment: I did now :) Apparently i still did everything right. I cleaned the project, resetted the simulator. The files are available, the xcode specific settings also

Comment: there is a bug that allow only png files for iOS, a quick fix to rename pencil extension to png, did you try it?

Comment: Suppose I would like to show one image from camera gallery. How can I show the image using the Image tag? It seems React Native always search for images in the assets and I cannot pass the image path from my local storage.